# How do I attach a gate where the swing end is 90 degrees to the wall?

Tags: wooden-furniture, gates

I have a gate which fits neatly between two walls running between my house and the next door neighbour.

For now, I have tethered the swing end with a simple loop of rope which tags onto a hook screwed into the wall.

Unfortunately, it's not too secure and easily slips off.  I'd prefer to have some kind of latch which is more secure and is able to withstand the weight of an excited fully grown dog.

[image]

Pictured here is the swing end of the gate, which is about 1.5 inches away from the wall.  Frustratingly, it's too narrow a gap for me to insert a post wide enough for a traditional latch.

Full context view:
[image]
Swing end to the left, hinge to the right - the gate swings away.  My wall is the one to the left.

I'm sure there's probably a simple solution to this one, but I can't figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

Take a (outdoor rated) board of appropriate thickness and attach it to the wall.

Mount the latch to that board.

Ask permission of your neighbour before drilling holes in his wall.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Do you have a photo/link to the type of latch that you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, would be to sink a 4"x4" in front of the gate where you want it to stop on the non-hinged side. You could then use a simple gate hook instead of a latch. Additionally, it would prevent the dog from being able to push it out at all since the post would bear the weight across the entire height.

Comment: Nice.  Best answer so far.  And this is a good way of stopping the gate from over-opening and trashing the hinges.

Answer (score 0):

Good ideas here, but I'm reluctant to drill holes in masonry in the first place, and a gate tends to impart a lot of force on fasteners and they may work loose over time.

I'd consider a "cane bolt". It would require you boring a hole in your walk, though.

[image]

<sup>[image source](https://www.houzz.com/photo/48263398-heavy-duty-dark-bronze-cane-bolt-for-gates-shown-holding-open-the-double-gate-craftsman-exterior-sacramento)</sup>

Comment: One downside of this solution is when the bolt gets dragged along the walk leaving a mark.

Comment: That's up to the user. There are extended and retracted positions. If you leave it dragging, it drags.